# Finding largest element in a two dimensional array

Tags: java

/*
   finding largest  element in an  2d array
*/
hi im trying to find the largest element in a two dimensional array can anybody help.the output i get is 8 but it should be 45

```
class LargestSmallestOfTwoDimensionalArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] data ={ {8,1,25,3,4},{45,12,13,2,3} };  // array of data


        int large = data[0][0];

        for(int i =0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
        {
           for(int j =i + 1 ; j < data.length ; j++)
           {
              if(large < data[i][j])
              {
                large= data[i][j];//checking and storing the largest element

              }
           }
        }

      System.out.println("Largest Element :" + large);
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps to log which fields you're checking. You may notice you never check `data[1][0]` or `data[1][1]`. In fact, it appears to me you only check `data[0][1]` and that's it.

Comment: `int j = i + 1` should also be `int j = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not checking every position in the array.

Change your code to this:

```
int[][] data ={ {8,1,25,3,4},{45,12,13,2,3} };  // array of data


    int large = data[0][0];

    for(int i =0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
    {
       for(int j =0 ; j < data[i].length ; j++)
       {
          if(large < data[i][j])
          {
            large= data[i][j];//checking and storing the largest element

          }
       }
    }

  System.out.println("Largest Element :" + large);
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in second loop, start at zero and check your condition:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length ; j++)
```

Remember, you need to check for the length of the inner list, not outer.